# Error "repository is not local" when doing HG update

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am trying to update to the latest pulled changes on Mercurial on a repo our team has been using for awhile.

```
C:\code\printlogix\templates-dev>hg update --clean
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
getting changed bfiles
abort: repository 'https://printlogix.kilnhg.com/Code/Repositories/Templates/templates-dev' is not local

C:\code\printlogix\templates-dev>
```

Not sure what this "repository xxxx is not local" message means, I have never seen this before.

For reference I am on TortoiseHg 2.5.1 (with Mercurial 2.3.2) on Windows 7 x64.  We also use KilnBfiles extension.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade to a new version of Mercurial?  You should try running the command again with `--debug` or `--traceback` set to see if it offers more information.

Answer (score 1):

Long shot, but I had this problem (hg v 2.4.2) and looked at the debug output and found the following.

```
calling hook preupdate.eol: <function preupdate at 0x000000000263A048>
lock: reading lock data from c9a8f1b931da
lock: reading d:\kev\htmapp\.hglocks@c9a8f1b931da <---- RELEVANT CLUE
using https://code.google.com/p/htmapp/
sending capabilities command
code.google.com certificate successfully verified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 88, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 741, in _dispatch`
```

I was using the hglocks extension, and after checking with the docs on the site discovered that its incompatible with anything newer than 2.3. Disabled the extension and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you need to setup TortoiseHG/Mercurial to use TortoisePlink for SSH support.  Details here:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Mercurial

Short version: add a line like the following to the [UI] section of your mercurial.ini file.

```
ssh = "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 -batch -C
```

Then logout & back in.  Not sure why that is necessary, but I couldn't get mercurial to pickup the mercurial.ini change until I did that.

For example, my mercurial.ini file looks like:

```
# Generated by TortoiseHg settings dialog
[extensions]
mq = 
rebase = 
transplant = 
hgsubversion = C:\Users\rsyring\dev\3rdparty\hgsubversion\hgsubversion
eol = 

[ui]
username = Randy Syring <me@nospam.com>
ssh = "C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2 -batch -C
```

Answer (score 0):

The Mercurial message in this case is not really descriptive. It helps to use `hg --debug -vvv --traceback` for your convert command to get more details.

Answer (score 0):

remove -R from your commandline

from this

```
hg pull -R URL -rREVISION
```

to this

```
hg pull -rREVISION URL
```